# Dynamic component SQL parameter type

Tags: component, sql, joomla-3.6

I'm looking to add a Component field which will display a list of Joomla users who have a relationship with current the Component item.

Below is some sample XML where by I would like `[current component id]` to be populated dynamically by the current component ID.

```
<field name="type"
       type="sql"
       query="SELECT id, name
              FROM #__users u
              JOIN #__customtable c ON u.id = c.user_id
              WHERE c.component_id = [current component id]"
       key_field="id"
       value_field="name"
       required="false"
       label="..."
       description="..."
       hint="..."
 />
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Sean, you have the privilege to vote in our current moderator [election](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/election?cb=1).  Please exercise your new democratic privilege.

Answer (score 1):

Not in the XML file as you have it - you'll need a custom field for this. You can then easily get your component item's id from the jinput and built your sql with that.

[Doc on making a custom field](https://docs.joomla.org/Creating_a_custom_form_field_type)

Comment: @Sean is this an "acceptable answer" or do you need something more?  Please always endeavor to progress your questions toward a clear resolution.